# Eclipse PyDev the outline view has a filter text box only and I can't get the outline back

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am using Eclipse v2021-3.  I accidentally hit some random key combo and the outline view cleared, showing only a text box to enter filter text.  I tried deleting the outline view and reopening, I tried shutting eclipse down and restart.  How do I get rid of the filter box and get my outline back?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Close:  The outline "miraculously" reappeared.....Mystery not Known